# Using CAS (Sage,Maxima,Octave?) with PHP (Linux), Converting LaTex to Sage / Octave script

Tags: php, latex, octave, sage

Hi for my student project I need to send a math expression (translated in TeX,LaTeX) from php server to some CAS and recieve its result back , translate it into LaTex (and e.g. compare it with my answer). I'm considering to use Sage(via console somehow) or Octave(octave-daemon?).

I am new in web developement and PHP and I am not sure if it works. So I have to translate LaTeX to some CAS-script(e.g. Octave Script) and read CAS output, and translate it to LaTeX.

Is it possible with Octave and Sage? Some code examples using Sage with php in Linux?

Is it possible to somehow **convert LaTex to Sage/Octave**? (I know Sage ->Latex is possible via **view()** or **Latex()** )

Comment: Some years ago I've created similar project. I used maxima because it has LaTeX-output (if you want). So it should work (can check http://cas.uzsolt.hu/ - only hungarian).

Comment: thank u for your answer. I have read that Sage Latex() represents Output in Latex. The Problem is to convert Latex to some CAS script. Because I would like to compare Output of CAS with my answer. E.g. LatexExpr->Converter->Cas(calculates Output in some script)->Converter->Latex == Latex<- myAnswer.

Comment: Octave isn't a CAS system. The symbolic package uses SymPy under the hood so you should rather use SymPy directly (without Octave)